# Can not get image path using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract image path from text like this:

```
body = 'some text here <br> <img src="/path/to/1234/some_Random_name24.jpg" class="img-responsive" /> </br>'
```

OR

```
body = '<br> Hi <img src="/path/to/15004/other_Random_name.png" class="img-responsive" /> other text'
```

My regexp:

```
match = re.search(r'src=\"(?P<path1>\"', body)
if match:
        print(match.group('path1'))
else:
        print("no match found")
```

But can not capture any path. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty hack, you could use

```
<img[^>]*src="([^"]+)
```

The golden path would be to use a parser though. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dLese8/2/).

---

In `Python` this could be

```
import re
junk = """body = 'some text here <br> <img src="/path/to/1234/some_Random_name24.jpg" class="img-responsive" /> </br>'

body = '<br> Hi <img src="/path/to/15004/other_Random_name.png" class="img-responsive" /> other text'"""

rx = re.compile(r'<img[^>]*src="([^"]+)')

sources = rx.findall(junk)
print(sources)
```

Which yields

```
['/path/to/1234/some_Random_name24.jpg', '/path/to/15004/other_Random_name.png']
```

See another [**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/0c5tFB).

Comment: How can I capture the matching path?